# Trying to add style with objects works with [ngClass], but not with [class]

Tags: css, angular, typescript

How's everyone?

I'm trying to add some class to a div on my template. The [Angular Mainsite](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) says, about styling:

> The NgClass directive can be used as an alternative to direct [class] bindings. However, using the above class binding syntax without NgClass is preferred because due to improvements in class binding in Angular, NgClass no longer provides significant value, and might eventually be removed in the future.

So, I're trying to do:

```
<div [class]="{class1:condition,class2:condition}"></div>
```

and

```
<div [class]="{'class1':condition,'class2':condition}"></div>
```

and it doesn't work. 
But with [NgClass] instead of [class], it runs perfectly. Someone knows why? 
I'm using Angular 8.2.14, and Angular Core 8.3.22.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't get the [class]={object} method to work either. [class.myStyle]="expression" does work however. But the docs clearly indicate the object method is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

ngClass and class are not used at all in the same way.

ngClass is waiting for a object, that's why your code works with this directive.

Class, on the other hand, is simply an HTML attribute.
If you want to add classes with conditions, you will have to work this way:

```
<div [class.class1]="condition"
     [class.class2]="condition"></div>
```

Hope to have helped you a little, see you soon!